# Designing the Select tag font-style

Tags: html, css

I just want to ask if its possible that the text in select is in italic then once the user chose an option, the text will change to normal? What I've done is when the uses is in select, the text is in normal style but once it focus out, the text change in to italic style. What I want is italic first then when the users chose, the text will change to normal. Here's the link to my work.  help. Thanks in advance. 
     http://jsfiddle.net/franscla/xcd0smxj/

```
`HTML
<div class='select'><select >
                                    <option>- Select subject -</option>
                                    <option >Purchase</option>
                                    <option style='height:50px;'>Be Our Partner</option>
                                    <option>Technical Problems</option>
                                    <option>Others</option>
                                </select></div>

CSS


   .select {
    margin-top:10px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    border: 1px solid #455d74;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 400px;
    font-family:Arial;

}

.select > select {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    border: 0 none;
    color: #7b7b7b;
    display: block;
    font-size:14px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 17px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 9px 6px 5px 9px;
    width: 100%;
    font-style:italic;
}
.select > select:focus {
    -moz-outline-radius: 2px;
    color: #000;
    outline: 0px solid #3fb6f2;
    outline-offset: 0;
    font-style:normal;
}


.select:before, .select:after {
    content: "";
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;


}
.select:before {
    background: inherit;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 29px;
}
.select:after {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    border-color: transparent transparent;
    background: url(http://www.8bitsports.net/wp-content/themes/morning/functions/wpzoom/assets/images/jquery.selectBox-arrow.gif) no-repeat 100% 100%;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    height: 15px;
    right: 6px;
    top: 6px;
    width: 10px;

}   


`
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this is what you want:

```js
$(".select").focusout(function() {
  $('select').addClass('newclass');
});
```

```css
.newclass {
  font-style: normal !important;
  color: black !important;
}
.select {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
  border: 1px solid #455d74;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 400px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.select > select {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
  border: 0 none;
  color: #7b7b7b;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 17px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 9px 6px 5px 9px;
  width: 100%;
  font-style: italic;
}
.select > select:focus {
  -moz-outline-radius: 2px;
  color: #000;
  outline: 0px solid #3fb6f2;
  outline-offset: 0;
  font-style: normal;
}
.select:before,
.select:after {
  content: "";
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
}
.select:before {
  background: inherit;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 29px;
}
.select:after {
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  border-color: transparent transparent;
  background: url(http://www.8bitsports.net/wp-content/themes/morning/functions/wpzoom/assets/images/jquery.selectBox-arrow.gif) no-repeat 100% 100%;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  height: 15px;
  right: 6px;
  top: 6px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='select'>
  <select>
    <option>- Select subject -</option>
    <option>Purchase</option>
    <option style='height:50px;'>Be Our Partner</option>
    <option>Technical Problems</option>
    <option>Others</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use javascript.